# DropBox core API how to get GPS metadata for each image?

Tags: objective-c, json, dropbox-api

I am using Core Api from drop box to upload and download file. The upload and download take place from my device. So the image is stored locally and then uploaded. And when downloaded they store on device and I pull them from their locations.

I am able to access the metaData dropBox provides via the restClient LoadedMetaData method. However that method doesn't provide support for the GPS. In this blog Post from dropBox https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/86/new-additional-information-about-photo-and-video-files

it has an update to access this. But it is done using a GET HTTP request. Can I do this from inside xcode? I tried accessing the request directly and it gives an error of "NO AUTH" so I cant grab the JSON file. But we should already be authorized from signing in directly with the api.

Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: Cross-linking with the Dropbox API forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=123031

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in the Core SDK, you can just call `[client loadMetadata:path withParams:@{@"include_media_info": @"true"}];`

(Caveat: I haven't tested it myself. Please let me know if it works.)

Comment: unfortunately rest client doesnt have that method. The only methods as such are: [self.restClient loadMetadata:<#(NSString *)#> atRev:<#(NSString *)#>];[self.restClient loadMetadata:<#(NSString *)#> withHash:<#(NSString *)#>];[self.restClient loadMetadata:loadDatas];

Comment: It's on line 118 of `DBRestClient.m`: `- (void)loadMetadata:(NSString*)path withParams:(NSDictionary *)params`. In fact, it's what all the other `loadMetadata` methods call. In any case, it turns out this won't work, because although you can make the request using this method, you won't be able to read the new fields out of the response, since the `DBMetadata` object doesn't have a way to access those fields. You'd have to modify that class to get this to work in the SDK.

Comment: Hmm, is there anyway to directly call the GET POST methods from inside xcode to access this?

Comment: I don't believe the SDK exposes the raw response unfortunately, so you would need to edit the source of the SDK to expose the additional information in DBMetadata. (Alternatively you could call the HTTP endpoints manually, but that would probably be more work.)

Comment: Greg, How would I go about either of those choices?